# Adding custom tab to single product page for specific product type in WooCommerce

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, tabs, product

Based on this code, I want to create custom tab for just variable products in WooCommerce **4.4.1**.

But unfortunately, this custom tab is added to all product types, is it any way to solve this problem?

If I am wrong please correct me.

```php
add_filter( 'woocommerce_product_tabs', 'woo_new_product_tab' );
function woo_new_product_tab( $tabs ) {
    
    // Adds the new tab for variable product type
    global $product;
 
    if( $product->is_type( 'variable' ) ) {
        
        $tabs['test_tab'] = array(
            'title'     => 'features',
            'priority'  => 50,
            'class'     => array('general_tab', 'show_if_variable'),
            'callback'  => 'woo_new_product_tab_content'
        );
    }

    return $tabs;
}
```

Comment: If you have some non-variable product this should work i guess. Maybe make your website print product type and you will see what's going on

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To find the error you can perform some extra checks and print the product type.
The `else` conditions can be removed after testing.

```php
function filter_woocommerce_product_tabs( $tabs ) {
    // Get the global product object
    global $product;
    
    // Is a WC product
    if ( is_a( $product, 'WC_Product' ) ) {
        // Get type
        $product_type = $product->get_type();
        
        // Compare
        if ( $product_type == 'variable' ) {        
            $tabs['test_tab'] = array(
                'title'     => 'features',
                'priority'  => 50,
                'callback'  => 'woo_new_product_tab_content'
            );
        } else {
            echo 'DEBUG: ' . $product_type;
        }
    } else {
        echo 'NOT a WC product';
    }

    return $tabs;
}
add_filter( 'woocommerce_product_tabs', 'filter_woocommerce_product_tabs', 10, 1 );

// Callback
function woo_new_product_tab_content() {
    // The new tab content
    echo '<h2>New Product Tab</h2>';
    echo '<p>Here\'s your new product tab.</p>';
}
```